# is it safe to keep all the status in the client when using react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, security, redux, client-side

I have been using server side rendering with different platforms for a while, before starting with React an Redux, but with this approach I have a mayor question: I seems as with them, status should be a single big object in the client. Leaving authentication beside, can this not be a security issue?.For example: I keep a status variable (accessLevel) that controls different menu items to only edit or edit+delete some kind of register in a data form. If I have the code in the client it seems I could some how alter accessLevel and change my permissions. Should in this cases have some status in the client and sensible data in the backend database?. Which is the approach?.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to keep all the status on the client side because you can't make a request for each and everything, it will affect user experience and performance of your application.

But, whenever you take an action, make a decision or change something which has to be saved in the backend, make sure you have a check of the status and everything to make sure that the action is a valid one.